# Username & password in OAuth2 request

Tags: oauth-2.0

I need to login to Dropbox programmatically (in code) IOT upload a file to an app.
All the examples I have found show `...username=xxx&password=yyy...`
I am sending "
'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?granttype=**password**&**username**=GreatDayDan&**password**=gggggggg&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8765'".

Dropbox replies:

> unknown field "username".

So, how should I include the username & password?

Comment: The [RFC section about that OAuth flow](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) says that the Access Token Request can/must contain `grant_type`, `username`, `password` and `scope`. But not `response_type` or `redirect_uri`. What happens if you exclude these last two from the request?

Comment: You seem to be using the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow. 
Looking at the [Dropbox OAuth guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide), it looks as if Dropbox does not support this particular flow. It says [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) that they support the code flow and the implicit grant flow.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, again. Should use **api.dropboxAPI.com** not **www.dropbox.com**.